# python package - include test suite or not

Tags: python, package, setuptools, distutils

The main question is: shall I include test suites for my code within the package or not? I do not mean neither a testing framework nor testing tools (such as nosetests) but the basic tests I run each time to check correctness of my code.

I've been following [setuptools tutorial](http://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html) and I have two modules: nac (the code itself) and `tests`. `setup.py` looks like the following:

```
setup(
    ...
    packages = ['nac', 'tests'],
    ...
)
```

And that's how it is installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`:

```
dist-packages/
  nac/
  tests/
```

I'm pretty sure that what I have now is not the ultimate solution, since `tests` package refers to `nac` package - but you can'f figure it out just by looking at `dist-packages` directory. I was thinking of creating one big `nac` module with 2 submodules: `core` and `tests`. Is it a good approach? Is there a standard pythonic way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better put the test cases underneath the main package, i.e. `nac.tests`. The test cases can use absolute import to load the main `nac` package.

```
nac-project/
    nac/
        tests/
    setup.py
```

In this way, you can run test cases against either 1) the local version, or 2) the deployed version of the `nac` package.

Comment: I like your idea. But still - is it a good approach to include tests into the distributed package?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz, I believe it is a common practice found in many packages available from PyPI. The concern is for end users to be able to verify a package after deployment, especially, when the package was deployed with third-party tools, say, `pip` or `easy_install`, and that the end users does not have direct access to the source tarball.